# Copy partitions to emmc with correct offsets

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, dd

I'm trying to populate an emmc in order to boot a custom Linux o.s. on an STM32MP1-based board.
[Here](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/STM32CubeProgrammer_flashlayout#e-E2-80-A2MMC) there is the schema of the partitions:

> TF-A copied in the two boot area partitions of e•MMC (hidden partition).
>
> GPT partitioning is used on the user area. U-Boot starts just after the GPT header at 17-Kbyte offset.
>
> The userfs partition is pre-populated with ext4 partition.

```
Opt     Part    Name     Type       Device  Offset      Binary
P       0x01    fsbl1    Binary     mmc1    boot1       tf-a.stm32
P       0x02    fsbl2    Binary     mmc1    boot2       tf-a.stm32
P       0x03    ssbl     Binary     mmc1    0x00080000  u-boot.stm32
P       0x10    bootfs   System     mmc1    0x00280000  bootfs.ext4.stm32
P       0x11    vendorfs FileSytem  mmc1    0x04280000  vendorfs.ext4.bin
P       0x12    rootfs   FileSytem  mmc1    0x05280000  rootfs.ext4.bin
P       0x13    userfs   FileSytem  mmc1    0x35280000  userfs.ext4.bin
```

I have the source partition files:

```
tf-a-myimage-trusted.stm32
u-boot-myimage-trusted.stm32
st-image-bootfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4
st-image-vendorfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4
st-image-rootfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4
st-image-userfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4
```

**1. How to convert the ext4 partitions to ext4.bin ones?**

My emmc appears as follow on the target:

```
# ls -l /dev/mmcblk2*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 16 Apr 18 08:03 /dev/mmcblk2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 32 Apr 18 08:03 /dev/mmcblk2boot0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 48 Apr 18 08:03 /dev/mmcblk2boot1
crw------- 1 root root 245,  0 Apr 18 08:03 /dev/mmcblk2rpmb
```

As far as I understand I have to copy the tf-a image into mmcblk2boot0 and mmcblk2boot1, then the others into mmcblk2 with their offsets (of course I will use the actual ones from the generated tsv file).

**2. Are these commands correct?**

```
dd if=/media/usb/tf-a-myimage-trusted.stm32 of=/dev/mmcblk2boot0 bs=8M
dd if=/media/usb/tf-a-myimage-trusted.stm32 of=/dev/mmcblk2boot1 bs=8M
dd if=/media/usb/u-boot-myimage-trusted.stm32 of=/dev/mmcblk2 conv=sparse seek=524288c bs=8M
dd if=/media/usb/st-image-bootfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4 of=/dev/mmcblk2 conv=sparse seek=1024 bs=512
dd if=/media/usb/st-image-vendorfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4 of=/dev/mmcblk2 conv=sparse seek=5120 bs=512
dd if=/media/usb/st-image-rootfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4 of=/dev/mmcblk2 conv=sparse seek=136192 bs=512
dd if=/media/usb/st-image-userfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4 of=/dev/mmcblk2 conv=sparse seek=1741824 bs=512
```

Comment: (1) The size of eMMC boot partitions is unlikely to be as large as 8 megabytes.  They could be 128KB.  (2) Simply copying images of the partitions to the storage device would not necessarily install any partition table, especially if the first 34 LBAs are not written (i.e. starting at offset 0).

Comment: @sawdust thanks, but I still not understand how to populate it in order to make the system boot from eMMC. Please, would you mind to elaborate a bit further your comment to make it an answer?

Comment: I'm not convinced that guide is accurate for an eMMC (as well as SD card) especially when it claims that *"GPT partitioning is used on the user area"*.    Rather than copying several images of partitions to the user area, consider making just one image for the user area using the genimage tool (which will also build a partition table, the missing piece in that guide)..

Comment: @sawdust, that was the first approach I tried but the technical support of ST said it won't work. Anyway, I had very poor experience with them... so if you think that is the correct way to boot from an STM32MP1 I invite you again to make it an answer, so we can discuss it better. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The layout used on STMP15x implies a GPT partition in eMMC user partition (as on SD-Card)

You can use the gpt command on the target (sgdisk for example) to create the partition table in user area:

```
$> sgdisk --resize-table=128 -a 1 \
-n 1:XXXX:XXXX          -c 1:ssbl \
-n 2:XXXX:XXXX          -c 2:bootfs \
-n 3:XXXX:XXXX          -c 3:vendorfs \
-n 4:XXXX:XXXX          -c 4:rootfs \
-n 5:XXXX:              -c 5:userffs \
-p /dev/mmcblk2
```

XXXX => needs to be computed with offset

Then you can copy each binary in each partition Y => mmcblk2pY

For example:

https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_update_U-Boot#Update_of_e-E2-80-A2MMC_with_the_Linux_dd_command

```
dd if=/media/usb/st-image-bootfs-openstlinux-eglfs-myimage.ext4 of=/dev/mmcblk2p2 conv=sparse seek=1024 bs=512
```

Or you can use:

```
./create_sdcard_from_flashlayout.sh to generated the user part of eMMC
```

This script originates from:
https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_populate_the_SD_card_with_dd_command

regards

Patrick